# "Чего интересного" - why genitive?

Tags: грамматика, родительный-падеж

I was watching a video, and in it, the girl asked, "Что интересного произошло для вас в этом году?" Why is genitive bring used here? I have another example: Много чего интересного. Can что in a sense be translated as "thing"? I often see что/чего being translated as " thing". But I often see что being replaced with чего for no reason! Can the genitive be used as almost an "abstract subject"? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: About the use of genitive with **что**, see this question: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8049/why-is-the-gentive-in-question-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'**Чего**' rather refers to '**много**' here than to 'интересного'. The colloquial *set expression* '**много чего** (такого)' basically means 'many such things (one could ask of or be interested in - too many to name all of them or to answer completely)'.

> -Что происходило в городе в этом году?
>
> -Много чего. (many things)

or:

> -Что важного, интересного или неожиданного было в этом году?
>
> -Много чего такого. (plenty of that kind)

So the genitive case of 'что' is adjusted for usage with the numeral 'много' (a noun in the place of this pronoun would have the same case). In your example the answer means 'many interesting things', with a flavour: too many for a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I often see что being replaced with чего for no reason!

Generally, it is often used in informal language, I doubt you would see that in any kind of official text.

Comment: The phrase 'много чего' is registered in some dictionaries as synonymous to 'изобилие' and is marked as colloquial (разг.), not informal (прост.). 
Словарь синонимов русского языка. Практический справочник. — М.: Русский язык. З. Е. Александрова. 2011
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/54258/изобилие

Comment: I mean the case when the single word "чего" has nothing to do with the phrase "много чего", for example - "Чего случилось?" - the same as "Что случилось?". I'm pretty sure that's the case that @kingkola36 meant in the second part of a question.